# Android Singleton Threadsafe

Tags: java, android, thread-safety, singleton

I have a threading, singleton, android question.

So let's say we have the following singleton code.

```
public class Singleton {
    private Singleton instance;
    private int number1 = 0;

    private Singleton() {
        //lots of initialization code
    }

    public static synchronized Singleton getInstance() {
        if(instance == null) {
            instance = new Singleton();
        }
        return instance;
    }
}
```

My question. Would access to number1 be threadsafe or would I need to create an accessor with a locking mechanism?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code won't compile, because `instance` is not static.  The declaration should read:

```
private static Singleton instance;
```

Other than that, you've set up a good mechanism to ensure that your application only has one instance of `Singleton`.

Doing this however, does not safeguard your member variable `number1` in any way. If you access that member variable from multiple threads, you'll still need to synchronize things properly.

Comment: I see. Thank you for your input. Would the preferred method be exposing a lock object so any thread can use the lock and then access the attributes, or accessor functions with the locking already within it?

Comment: I would do all of the locking inside your `Singleton` class and just expose accessors. That way, you can change up your implementation internally if needed.

Comment: @DoubleDunk - he means instead of declaring `private Singleton instance;` you need `static private Singleton instance;` -- because your static getInstance() method needs to access it.

Comment: @mah Thanks for the clarification, my second question was towards accessing the attributes themselves. Wsanville, Thanks you very much for your input, I know have a direction. However, I do have one last question. Is synchronization an expensive operation in terms of context switching if the singleton is being accessed frequently? Is there another way to share data among let's say 3 threads? Thanks.

Comment: Synchronization/locking isn't expensive by itself, and that is the way to go if you want to ensure freshness of data in each thread. If however, you end up doing a ton of work inside a locked/syncronized block of code, then yeah the end result could be expensive.

Answer (score 5):

Making an object a singleton does nothing at all to affect thread safety. If you're going to be using your singleton from multiple threads, you will need to manage data synchronization as needed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As I suspected I need to do synchronization on my datatypes. Thanks again.

Comment: @DoubleDunk may I ask why my answer was not accepted? I thought I answered you (first) and you understood the answer. If you feel wsanville's answer was more helpful then I fully respect that, but I would like to understand it if you don't mind. It's rather disheartening to think I've helped someone but to not receive the proper feedback.

Comment: You are absolutely right, your answer was very helpful. However, I feel like wsanville went into more detail and even corrected my code. If there was a way to split the answer I would. Thank you for your help and believe me, I would like to split the answer. :)

Comment: Actually quite the contrary. Thank you for your help, you were of great assistance good sir. Take care.